# Meteor how to use Meteor.wrapAsync with facebook Graph Api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, asynchronous, meteor

I solved Graph Api asynchronous request by using fibers/future, which allows to give function result after predefined amount of time, downside of this solution is when facebook sends response faster than 1000ms it will wait anyway.

Is there any way to make Server Side function which returns graph api result right after response comes? I have found **Meteor.wrapAsync** could be helpful, but I'm not sure i get it's syntax correctly.

Here's what I have done using fibers and it's working exactly one second.

```
function graphGet(query){

    var response = new Future(); // wait for async FB response
    var waitingTime = 1000;
    var graphResponse = "no result after: " + waitingTime + "ms";

    FBGraph.get(query, function(error, response) {
      if (response) { graphResponse = response; }
      else { graphResponse = error; }
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
      response['return'](graphResponse);
    }, waitingTime);

  return response.wait();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same code using `Meteor.wrapAsync` is much shorter :

```
function graphGet(query){
  // wrap the async func into a FBGraph bound sync version
  var fbGraphGetSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(FBGraph.get, FBGraph);
  // use a try / catch block to differentiate between error and success
  try{
    var result = fbGraphGetSync(query);
    return result;
  }
  catch(exception){
    console.log(exception);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! replaced my fiber - based function with Your WrapAsync solution and now it gives result as soon as facebook responds.

Comment: [update] Added callback functionality by changing to `graphGet(query,callback)` and adding `if(callback){callback()};` before return.

Comment: I tried to use it as is on my server side, but I always get a : { stack: [Getter] } exception ... any idea why ? @saimeunt ? Author ?